# Bootstrap 3: Can't use rgba background color in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change bootstrap's navigation bar background color to a lower opacity rgba one but I can't. No changes are made at all. This is my custom navbar's css:

```
    .navbar-custom {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3) }
```

And this is my html navbar code:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        NAVBAR CONTENT GOES HERE
    </nav>
```

Comment: `rgba(255,255,255,.3)` instead of `rgba(255,255,255.3)`;

Comment: Sorry, I already use the right syntax, I just typed it wrong here. Still doesn't work.

Comment: are you able to set bg color using any other syntax e.g. hex code, or color name e.g. red?

Comment: Yes. Rgba is the only one that doesn't work.

Comment: Working fine for me: http://www.bootply.com/EgDDU70dWa

Comment: That means that there is something else wrong with my code right? I just noticed I can't use rgba color on li a either. http://i.imgur.com/4zjnLA0.png

Comment: Can you attach a link of your website? What browser are you using?

Comment: It's a local website on xampp. I'm using Chrome, I also tried firefox, doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

rgba(255,255,255,.3) instead of rgba(255,255,255.3);

Comment: Sorry, I already use the right syntax, I just typed it wrong here. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, make use of important if you want override the property .

```
.navbar-custom {
      background-color: rgb(255,255,0)  !important;
   }
```

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to set its color to a faded white. Here is an image: http://i.imgur.com/4zjnLA0.png

Answer (score 0):

It works perfect... probably there is some override in your implementation, open the computed stylesheet panel of your inspector and find that property.

this is the current support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors

```css
.navbar-custom {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, .3);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">NAVBAR CONTENT GOES HERE</nav>
```

Comment: Yeap, something is wrong... Is it possible to find what? http://i.imgur.com/dMIWpQg.png

Comment: You need to inspect the `.navbar-custom` element that doesn't work, if you are using chrome: *right click on it and inspect element*, then, in the *element panel* click on the *computed* tab and find the computed background color, click again and see which rule applied,

Comment: it seems that anything is applying, so, probably your css isn't loaded... where are you putting this rule `.navbar-custom { background: rgba(0, 255, 255, .3); }` ??

Comment: In my custom CSS stylesheet which I linked to the page below bootstrap's stylesheet. Everything else included in this stylesheet works fine.

Comment: what are you saying is impossible to happen :)

Comment: I know! I've been struggling with this for more than an hour! I will post a link when the website is online.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you declare your custom stylesheet in your head, that your custom stylesheet is declared below your bootstrap declaration. For example:

```
<link href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This will ensure the default bootstrap settings can be overwritten by your custom styles.

Comment: Yes, the custom css stylesheet is below bootstrap.